# In Ansible, can one loop over a dictionary in reverse?

Tags: ansible

Ansible v2.11

Say I have a dictionary of services I want to either start or stop, like this. You notice that the last 2 services are dependent on the first service

```
exa_web_services:
  EXA_Web:
    description: "Exa Web service"
    app_dir: "{{ exa_web_dir }}"
    app_cmd: "{{ node_exe }}"
    app_cmd_params: "app.js EXA_Web env={{ node_environment }} port=8080 ssl_port=8443"
    dependency: "EXA_Redis_Cache"
  EXA_Web_APIs:
    description: "Exa Web APIs service"
    app_dir: "{{ exa_web_dir }}"
    app_cmd: "{{ node_exe }}"
    app_cmd_params: "app.js EXA_Web_APIs env={{ node_environment }} port=8091 mode=api"
    dependency: "EXA_Web"
  EXA_Print_Service:
    description: "Exa Print service"
    app_dir: "{{ exa_web_dir }}"
    app_cmd: "{{ node_exe }}"
    app_cmd_params: "app_service.js SERVICE_NAME=PRINTSERVICE"
    dependency: "EXA_Web"
```

To start the services I do, which starts them in the correct order

```
  - name: Start the services
    win_service:
      name: "{{ item.0 }}"
      state: started
    loop: "{{ exa_web_services.items() }}"
```

However, if I try to stop the services similarly, it fails since it stops the first service first, `EXA_Web`, but it has dependencies, the last 2 services.

```
  - name: Start the services
    win_service:
      name: "{{ item.0 }}"
      state: stopped
    loop: "{{ exa_web_services.items() }}"
```

So how can I loop over the dictionary in reverse so I stop the last 2 services first, then `EXA_Web`? Is it possible? I know I can add `force_dependent_serves: true` attribute and be done with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way we can achieve this, is by using the `dict2items` [filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#dict-filter) and then `reverse` it.

Something like this:

```yaml
- name: stop the services
  win_service:
    name: "{{ item.key }}"
    state: "stopped"
  loop: "{{ exa_web_services | dict2items | reverse | list }}"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly btw, thanks!